# ibm rad 8, was 7, spring 3.2.9 and xerces problem

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, websphere, websphere-7, xerces

I know this is a long shot, but I have to ask. I have a Spring 3.2.9 web project in RAD8 running on WAS 7 with xerces.jar library on WIN 7 32bit. I use WAS 7 JRE which is Java 6. Everything is ok, but I wanted more RAM to use, so I moved everything to WIN 7 64bit. So, now I have RAD 8 32bit running on WIN 7 64 bit and my Spring app won't start due to: "parserConfigurationException unable to validate using XSD, your jaxp provider does not support XML schema, upgrade to Xerces or java 5".

I have tried answers from stackoverflow. When I try to add VM arguments to WAS 7, the server won't start anymore. When I move Xerces to RAD8 endorsed folder, nothing changes. I added/removed xerces.jar, nothing changes. I repeat, it works in WIN 7 32bit.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have solved the problem, and it was much simpler than what I have tried before (see question). Here is my take on things if someone has the same predicament. I did not know what to do anymore, so I removed every configuration option from WAS 7 that works on WIN 7 32bit, and started from scratch on WIN 7 64bit, turning on/off configuration options on WAS 7 as I go.

**The problem was in “classloader”**. I set it to *“load parent last”* and that works on WIN 7 32bit. But, in WIN 7 64bit, I have to set to ***“load parent first”***. I don’t know what to say. While this has solved my problem, I still don’t know why the same setup doesn’t work on both OS.